# VS Code opens header files while debugging a code in C++. How to prevent this from happening?

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

Before I started Debugging:
[image: Before I started Debugging]

After I started Debugging:
[image: After I started Debugging]

As it can be seen in the second image, `allocator.h` header file is being opened when the debugger ecountered a vector in the first image (highlighted in yellow line). Whole debugging process is so annoying and time taking this when this happens. How to stop this from happening?

VS Code version : 1.78.2
OS : Windows 10

I tried resetting VS Code to defaults, but couldn't fix the problem.

Comment: please add the version number of your C++ extension(s), and provide a [mre] (code that can be used to reproduce the issue)